# Inno Setup - How to set full permission on a folder, not just for it's contents

Tags: permissions, directory, inno-setup

My kit created with Inno Setup installs my application in `C:\Program Files\MyApp`.

When my application starts, it tries to create new log files in `C:\Program Files\MyApp\logs\` but it fails.

In my Inno script i have the following settings:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}";

[Files]
Source: logs\*; DestDir: {app}\logs\; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Permissions: everyone-full
```

This gives full permissions on all files inside `logs` folder, but not on the folder itself. So, when my application tries to create a new log file inside that folder, it fails.

How can i set full permissions on the folder as well, not only on the existing files in it?

Comment: The [`same as here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580222/creating-folder-for-log-files-for-nlog-with-innosetup#comment25581266_17580222) applies for you.

Comment: @TLama thanks for the link, i will try it and come back with the results

Comment: Whenever possible, avoid using full permissions and use modify instead.

Answer (score 24):

Setting permissions for `logs` folder under [Dirs] section worked for me:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}"; 
Name: "{app}\logs"; Permissions: everyone-full

[Files]
Source: logs\*; DestDir: {app}\logs\; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Permissions: everyone-full
```

But, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580222/creating-folder-for-log-files-for-nlog-with-innosetup#comment25581266_17580222), i'm not sure if it's the proper way to do it.

Comment: everyone-full is maybe too much, from the doc it looks like users-modify is enough.
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=dirssection
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection

Comment: @Joël Cool. Thanks for mentioning modify permission and the documentation.

Answer (score 13):

Simply using the following code works for me and I think it is more *secured*:

```
[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\logs"; Permissions: users-full
```

Comment: You're right about "users" instead of "everyone". Still, as the linked posts have said, "full" is probably unnecessary. In fact, my app only worked once I set the permissions to "modify", because the system wouldn't let me set permissions to "full".

Comment: Your solution was the simplest and worked just fine for me!