# Inno setup - allowing database modification

Tags: inno-setup

my application includes a `db` and users will be able to add data to the `db` via a GUI. So I need to give authorization to the user to modify the `db`. I tried all options from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596054/inno-setup-how-to-set-full-permission-on-a-folder-not-just-for-its-contents/17596875) but authorization is still not allowed.
Here, this is an illustration of what I try to achieve (get Permissions for Modify checked in the "Allow" column):

[image]

Here my current code:

```
#define MyAppName "aaa"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppExeName "aaa.exe"

[Setup]
AppId={{...-...-...-...-...}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=C:\...\output
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Dirs]
Name: "{app}\Logs"; Permissions: everyone-modify

[Files]
Source: "C:\...\aaa.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\...\list_files\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Permissions: everyone-modify
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

How can I give database access to the user through the creation process of the setup? Thank you

Comment: You should not store data into installation folder in the first place.

Comment: I followed your advice but permission is still not allowed.

Comment: I see `{app}\Logs` in your script.

Comment: I am a rookie in `inno setup`, should I remove the section `[Dirs]` from my code?

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl, based on your comments above, I managed to resolve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\...\aaa.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\...\folder_files\*"; DestDir: "{localappdata}\name_application\folder_files\"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Comment: Do not grant all users write access to *Program Files* folder! That's a hack, not a solution. See also [Application does not work when installed with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44333839/850848).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I said, I am a novice and maybe my following question can be basic: I understand that I have to put my `db` in the `AppData\Local` folder but my `exe` has to be in the `Program Files` folder or it can be located in the `AppData\Local` folder with the `db` ?

Comment: If the application is to be used by all users of the machine, it should be in `Program Files`. If it is to be used by the user that installed it only, it can be in `AppData\Local`.

Comment: Based on Martin Prikryl's comment, I switched the `DestDir` for `{localappdata}` instead of `{app}`